# 12.04 NetworkManager trying to configure eth0 which is on a bridge

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, network-bridge

For months I've been running 12.04 headless home server with a bridge connected through eth0. I've been using this `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 auto br0
 iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.8.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.8.0
        broadcast 192.168.8.255
        gateway 192.168.8.2
        dns-nameservers 192.168.8.2
        dns-search cluster.toy
        pre-up ip link set eth0 down
        pre-up brctl addbr br0
        pre-up brctl addif br0 eth0
        pre-up ip link set eth0 up
        post-down ip link set eth0 down
        post-down ip link set br0 down
        post-down brctl delif br0 eth0
        post-down brctl delbr br0
```

However, after a weird network error I looked at my logs and saw that NetworkManager was repeatedly trying to bring up eth0, which it absolutely should not be doing (eth0 is a slave to br0, which is statically configured).

My understanding is that since I have NetworkManager.conf set with this setting:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

It is supposed to ignore any interfaces mentioned in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.  So I have some questions:

- Am I missing something, or is there a bug in NetworkManager that it doesn't parse bridge stanzas in `/etc/network/interfaces` correctly to know to ignore them?
- Is there some sort of dummy statement I now have to put in `/etc/network/interfaces` to trick network manager into leaving it alone?
- Alternatively, can I just `apt-get remove network-manager` with no negative consequences?

Comment: Note this config was copied over from my old server which was originally running 6.06.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. NetworkManager tries to manage eth0 because eth0 is not configured in /etc/network/interfaces.
2. To cause NetworkManager not to touch eth0, add the following stanza to /etc/network/interfaces.

   `iface eth0 inet manual`
3. If you aren't using NetworkManager then you can safely remove network-manager.

By the way, there's an easier way to configure bridges in /e/n/i. Use the bridge_* options as illustrated in the answer by bodhi.zazen.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I didn't know about the `manual` option, or about the newer-then-when-I-created-this-file bridge_ports option.  I also seem to recall times that network-manager was tied to things like ubuntu-desktop so that it couldn't be removed easily.  I've simplified the file and its removed network-manager, that should keep things happy from now on.

Comment: I also think I'll file a bug report to have network-manager ignore interfaces listed in bridge_ports (unless it already does? hmm)

Answer (score 1):

NetworkManager does not handle bridges. This has been a long standing shortcoming of NetworkManager. If you want a bridge, you need to disable NetworkManager and use ifup instead, configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Example:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxwait 5
```